# Подмена страницы

Tags: php

Вопрос такой. Имеем страницу, к примеру `/srr/`; также имеем более легкую версию страницы `srr.html`. Теперь вопрос: как при загрузке страницы `/srr/` загружать `srr.html`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/srr/` - это не страница, а путь к каталогу с файлами сайта.

Если вы используете Apache, то есть два пути осуществить то, что вы хотите.

1. [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) и [туда же](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)
2. Добавить к директиве `DirectoryIndex` в конфигурационном файле Apache  `srr.html`. Это плохой вариант